# Can't access the Array in Object which I fetched

Tags: reactjs, fetch

When I try to get the Array from an object which I fetched, I keep getting errors like there is no Array in your Object.
But If I log the whole Object there is definitely the Array exists...

Also, I can access the Array in the fetch function, but I can't if I put the object in the state...

Can anybody tell me why two things, In the fetch Function & outside of the fetch Function is working differently?

Down below is my code

```
function App() {

  const [data,setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    console.log(data);
  }, []);


  const getData = async () => {
    await fetch(
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/league/2",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "3d3a997c8fmsh72c953500760ae9p12f8bcjsn336cae28920b",
        },
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.api.teams);
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };


  console.log(data.api)

  return (
    <>
      <Div></Div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are setting data and then immediately logging `data`, but the component hasn't re-rendered yet so the state has not changed. Data is updated only after re-render.  Also you shouldn't be setting state inside an async function without first checking that the `setData` function still exists. The component could have unmounted by the time the request resolves.

Comment: But if I console.log it I can get the object of which I fetched. But the Array is the thing I can't get.. Can you tell me what's different between inside the fetch and outside the fetch which ```data``` State?